# Laravel object value with Blade statement does not work if model has accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, accessor

i have an Laravel object model with accessor:

```
class NutritionalPlanRow extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    private $nomeAlimento;

    public function __construct($aliment = null,
                                array $attributes = array())  {

        parent::__construct($attributes);

        if($aliment){
            $this->aliment()->associate($aliment);
            $this->nomeAlimento = $aliment->nome;
        }
    }

    public function aliment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Aliment');
    }

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getNomeAlimentoAttribute()
    {
        return $this->nomeAlimento;
    }
}
```

and i want to print the **nomeAlimento** value in a Blade page with Blade statement, for example:

```
 .
 .
 <tbody>
     @foreach( $plan->nutritionalPlanRows as $planRow )
     <tr>
         <td>
             {{ $planRow->nomeAlimento}}
         </td>
   .
   .
```

but the value inside the table cell is not printed, as if $planRow->foodName is null. In reality it is not empty, in fact if I print {{$planRow}} the structure of the object is complete, and all the attributes are set.
I noticed that if in the model I remove the accessor (getNomeAlimentoAttribute()), then the value in the blade page is correctly printed.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Some things to have in mind (this are my personal tips after working with Laravel for 5 years): Do not use string namespaces (like `App\Models\Aliment`), use `Aliment::class` as your IDE will recognize it and help you better, also you will see the `use` on top and if you have a lot, there is something that is not right on that class. Another thing, try to write your code ALWAYS in English, it will help you with it and also be readable for anyone. And last 2 tips, **DO NOT** associate things or similar on `constructor`, if you do `New NutritionalPlanRow`, `$this->aliment()` should not exist.

Comment: And that is going to be confusing, a `Model` should not have logic inside like that and worst on the `constructor`, that should be a `domain` or `controller` class taking care of that... and why are you writing an accessor returning same stuff as if you didn't have that accessor ? I cannot recall right now, but I think your problem is that `getNomeAlimentoAttribute()` is for `$model->nome_alimento` and not `$model->nomeAlimento`. Read more about it on the [beautiful documentation Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) has....

Comment: What happens if you have getNomeAlimentoAttribute() return a static string instead? Maybe the var you're trying to return has no value.

Comment: @Kobazzo there's no need to initialise calculated attributes with `private $years`. Also if `day_born` is a column on the table storing the model records, there's no need to initialise it as class property `private $day_born`

Comment: To get years, can be done as `\Iluminate\Support\Carbon::now()->diffForHumans($this->day_born)`. Laravel offers a wrapper around `Carbon\Carbon` the very popular date handling library for PHP

Comment: @Kobazzo I tried to club your further query with your own question but seems its still stuck pending community approval for the edit - sorry about that.

Comment: @Donkarnash 
Thanks. But if I don't define the list of attributes in the model, even if they are columns on the database, how do I call them from the controller when I want to use them? Do I have to remember all the attributes of the model by heart or always declare get and set, accessors/mutators for all? Also I initialized the variable years in the model so I just call the getter to get the result everywhere, and avoid doing the calculation whenever I need.

Comment: If you want to record all the column ($attributes) on a model you can use `$fillable = [array of all the attributes which can be mass assigned]` instead of `$guarded = []`.  However even if you don't list all column attributes in `$fillable` they are available in the controller and views. There's no need to define/declare attributes which are present as column on database. Calculation will be done for all accessor/calculated attributes each time because even if you store them as instance properties they are available/cached only till the instance is available.

Comment: @Donkarnash using 

1.
I removed from the attribute list $ dayBorn. Now in the controller if I try to ask the attributes from the Patient instance, $ patient->day...  the lIDE doesn't give me any suggestions, this forces me to remember the name of all the attributes by heart. Am I wrong something?

Carbon::parse($this->dayBorn)->diffForHumans(now()); 

2.
$this->dayBorn is null (also $this->day_born is null) but if i print $this is present. If i use $this['dayBorn'] the value is present.

Comment: @Kobazzo I think I misunderstood, did you mean that by declaring the attributes as model instance properties you get intellisense in editors but otherwise you may have to remember all the column/attributes?

Comment: @Donkarnash exactly, unless I declare for all fields getter and setters

Comment: @Kobazzo For that Laravel developers usually use PHP Doc annotations before the class declaration

Comment: @Donkarnash Perfect! I come from Java :)

Comment: @Donkarnash "PHP Doc annotations before the class declaration", what is the correct way to add attributes annotations before the class declaration?

Comment: @Kobazzo `@property int $id Unique identifier for the object` before the class declaration within `/** Dock blocks */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need attention:

First: Why do you need a constructor? You can define a calculated attribute without the constructor

```php
use App\Models\Aliment;

class NutritionalPlanRow extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
  
   

    public function aliment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Aliment::class);
    }

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getNomeAlimentoAttribute()
    {
        return optional($this->ailment)->nome;
    }
}
```

Second: It seems like a code smell when using constructor in Eloquent Model class to set relations. Ideally relations should be set/associated from within Controller.

Third: I feel declaring `$nomeAlimento` as private property on the class is not required. In Laravel calculated properties/attributes can be provided with accessors.

Update:

```php
class Patient extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $dates = ['day_born'];
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getYearsAttribute(){
        
        Log::info('patient all data '.$this);  //Print correct all data
        Log::info('Day'.$this->day_born); //print empty
        
        
        return Carbon::parse($this->day_born)->diffForHumans(now());
    }
}
```

Read https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ for more goodies.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
First: the purpose of a constructor then what is it?
Third: the theory does not want variables to be private and to be manipulated only through accessor and mutator (or getter and setter)? And what name should i use for $nomeAlimento accessor?

Thank you.

Comment: First: Laravel model classes rarely require constructor. What you seem to be doing in the constructor is to associate Aliment record to NutirtionalPlanRow. In Laravel world normally the association/dis-association of related model records take place in Controller.

Comment: Third: Yeah you're right declaring private variables with getters/setters or accessors/mutators is common. However the point I tried to make is that you don't need a private variable in Laravel model class. An accessor can be defined to provide calculated properties.

Comment: For a scenario where you are creating a new `NutirtionalPlanRow` for a particular existing `Aliment` it can always be done as `$aliment->nuttitionalPlanRows()->create([...$data]);`. There's not need to have the logic in constructor. Laravel relationships can be used to ensure proper association between related models while creating new records.

Comment: @Kobazzo I have updated the answer to include your query regarding the calculated attribute on `Patient` class